# Set interval for $().text inside of div

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Below is my code, I will try to best explain my issue. I have some information coming in from a JSON file (json file gets updated every second) which I then use to display moving markers and put the info inside a div. How ever the information inside the div is not updating, so for example I have a plane altitude which is changing live as it comes in to land. When I first click on the marker it will load the altitude but will not update it inside the div accordingly. If I refresh the page it will show the latest altitude but this is not practical refreshing the page every second. I was thinking a window.setInterval but I cannot get it to work. I did try:

> ```
> > function refreshdiv(){
> > 
> >   google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
> >     console.log("hello" + value.hex);
> >       
> >     var imageurl;
> >       $.get('https://ae.roplan.es/api/hex-image.php?hex='+value.hex,
>          function (response) { 
> >         imageurl = response;
> >         if (imageurl == ""){
> >             $( "#image" ).attr('src', "imageerror.jpg");
> >         }
> >         else {
> >             $( "#image" ).attr('src', imageurl);
> >             
> >         }
> >         
> >       });
> > 
> > 
> >     $( "#reg" ).load("/aireg.php?hex="+value.hex);
> >     $( "#type" ).load("/airtype.php?hex="+value.hex);
> >     $( "#ser" ).load("/airser.php?hex="+value.hex);
> >     $( "#owner" ).load("owner.php?hex="+value.hex);
> >     $( "#origin" ).load("orig.php?flight="+value.flight);
> >     $( "#des" ).load("routes.php?flight="+value.flight);
> >     $( "#hex" ).text(value.hex+"");
> >     $( "#callsign" ).text(value.flight + "");
> >     $( "#radar" ).text(value.seen + "s");
> >     $( "#vertrate" ).text(value.vert_rate + " fpm");
> >     $( "#altitude" ).text(value.altitude+" ft");
> >     $( "#speed" ).text(value.speed+" kts");
> >     $( "#course" ).text(value.track+ "째");
> >     document.getElementById("sidebar").style.display = "block"; 
>   window.setInterval(refreshdiv, 1000);   }); }
> ```

But the Div did not open. Any ideas on what I might be doing wrong? Any help is appreciated.

```
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    console.log("hello" + value.hex);

    var imageurl;
      $.get('https://ae.roplan.es/api/hex-image.php?hex='+value.hex, function (response) { 
        imageurl = response;
        if (imageurl == ""){
            $( "#image" ).attr('src', "imageerror.jpg");
        }
        else {
            $( "#image" ).attr('src', imageurl);

        }

      });


    $( "#reg" ).load("/aireg.php?hex="+value.hex);
    $( "#type" ).load("/airtype.php?hex="+value.hex);
    $( "#ser" ).load("/airser.php?hex="+value.hex);
    $( "#owner" ).load("owner.php?hex="+value.hex);
    $( "#origin" ).load("orig.php?flight="+value.flight);
    $( "#des" ).load("routes.php?flight="+value.flight);
    $( "#hex" ).text(value.hex+"");
    $( "#callsign" ).text(value.flight + "");
    $( "#radar" ).text(value.seen + "s");
    $( "#vertrate" ).text(value.vert_rate + " fpm");
    $( "#altitude" ).text(value.altitude+" ft");
    $( "#speed" ).text(value.speed+" kts");
    $( "#course" ).text(value.track+ "째");
    document.getElementById("sidebar").style.display = "block";

  });
```

Comment: `refreshdiv !== refershdiv`. You have a typo.

Comment: Also, if you [open the Dev Tools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools) you might see an error in the console about this.

Comment: also, setInterval is not like setTimeout, you have to call it only once, not after each refresh.

Comment: @E.Sundin typo was only on this site when I re typed it.:)

Comment: What are all those elements like #reg?  Are they accessible when that code is executed?  That is, does console.log($('#reg')) return what you expect?  Is there more than one #reg?

Comment: @Rob The reg is in a txt file which corresponds to the hex from the json when I click on the marker it query the txt file and gets the reg. The reg updates for each marker but not the .text ones like value.flight need to somehow control the variable or refresh selected marker?

Comment: OK, does the #callsign element exist at that point in the code?  That is, does console.log($('#callsign')) return what you expect?

Comment: @Rob the #callsign is the div id so I have <div id="callsign"></div>. This div displays the call sign when someone clicks on the marker. But it does not update it so some times when I new aircraft comes into to the reciver range it will show other aircraft call signs or undefined unlesss I refresh the page but does not update at interval which is what I need. Happens with all of the .txt ones. Altitude stays the same even though in the json file it is live unless I refresh the page.

Comment: Is there more than one <div id="callsign"></div>?

Comment: Multiple div's but only one div for call sign.

Comment: @Rob              <div id="aircraftinfo">
            Aircraft Callsign: <div style="font-size:17px;" id="callsign">n/a</div>
            Aircraft Registration: <div style="font-size:17px;" id="reg">n/a</div>
            Owner:<div style="font-size:17px;" id="owner">n/a</div>
            Aircraft Type:<div style="font-size:17px;" id="type">n/a</div>
            Aircraft Hex:<div style="font-size:17px;" id="hex">n/a</div>
            Aircraft Serial No:<div style="font-size:17px;" id="ser">n/a</div>

Comment: I gather that this div is inside an info window.  Is there more than one info window?  If so, it might be the case that you have more than one element with the same ID.  Does console.log($('#callsign')) return only one element at the point in the code you're trying to update it?